# Error on attaching a policy to aws cognito pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

I am getting following error when I am trying to attach IOT policy to aws cognito pool. I try to attach policy from CLI. Can someone help me get rid of following error.

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the AttachPrincipalPolicy operation: Invalid principal type
```

I am getting this error after running the following command.

```
aws iot attach-principal-policy --policy-name 'myPolicy' --principal 'us-east-2_XXXXX' --region 'us-east-2'
```

Is there any way to attach policy from AWS GUI.

Thanks

Comment: "The principal, which can be a certificate ARN (as returned from the CreateCertificate operation) or an Amazon Cognito ID." in your case, what is `us-east-2_XXXXX`?

Comment: Thanks Marcin. us-east-2_XXXXX is a pool id. I am confused by certificate . Certificate is that certificate which received when i created the iot thing or its related to cognito

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is that you are passing the Pool Id, however in that field you must pass the Identity Pool Id.

[Identity pool Id example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVYbU.png)

```
foo@bar:~$ aws iot attach-principal-policy --policy-name 'real-time-weather-iot-policy' --principal 'us-west-2:<identity_pool_id>' --region us-west-2
```